# How do you run a Cypher Query on a Neo4j Database in Go?

Tags: go, neo4j

I've been working on this problem for a few hours, and I haven't had much luck with the community Golang drivers for Neo4j.

I've attempted to run "movies-go-cq" and "neoism" examples. The [movies-go-cq](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-go-cq) example doesn't work for me, [it crashes when localhost:8080 is loaded in the browser](http://imgur.com/a/OkbwN).

Cypher queries on my Neo4j database with neoism only return empty/blank data. However, when I run the same query in the Neo4j browser at localhost:7474, the expected data is returned.

Here is the Go code I am running with neoism:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jmcvetta/neoism"
)

func main() {
    // Reference: https://godoc.org/github.com/jmcvetta/neoism

    // Connect to the Neo4j server
    db, _ := neoism.Connect("http://localhost:7474/db/data")

    // Issue a query
    res1 := []struct {
        A string `json:"path1"` // `json` tag matches column name in query
        B string `json:"path2"`
    }{}
    cq1 := neoism.CypherQuery{
        // Use backticks for long statements - Cypher is whitespace indifferent
        Statement: `
        MATCH path1 = shortestPath( (plant:Plant {Term: "Vaccinium corymbosum"})-[*..5]-(gene:Gene {Description: "adenylate cyclase activating polypeptide 1"}) )
        MATCH path2 = shortestPath( (gene)-[*..5]-(disease:Medical_Heading {Term: "Alzheimer Disease"}) )
        RETURN path1, path2
        `,
        Result: &res1,
    }
    db.Cypher(&cq1)
    r := res1[0]
    fmt.Println(r.A, r.B)
}
```

I am considering writing my own API wrapper in Go that uses Neo4j's HTTP RESTful API if I can't get existing Go drivers to work properly; I am new to Golang, and I would be thankful for any advice for debugging Go code or tips for working with Neo4j in Golang. Thank you for your time.

Comment: [db.Cypher](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmcvetta/neoism#Database.Cypher) returns an error. Can you capture that (`err := db.Cypher(&cq1)`) and update your question with the value of `err` ?

Answer (score 0):

I know what you are facing right now. Some time before I was facing the same issue. 
There are 2 possible cases are there:-

1) You should always declare struct variable Capital.

`` res1 := []struct {
        CAPITAL_STR1 string `json:"path1"`
        CAPITAL_STR2 string `json:"path2"`
    }{} ``

which you are doing exactly right A and B.

2) You have to paste exact json type (There is mistake)

`` res1 := []struct {
        CAPITAL_STR1 string `json:"path1.distance"`
        CAPITAL_STR2 string `json:"path2.distance"`
    }{} ``

For getting exact json format check output json response at your Neo4J in browser. It is available under section code.

Comment: Thank you, Shivendra! I will check this while looking at my code tomorrow at work.